# Find specific IE11 version with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, polymer

I've read a few threads on this, but I didn't get a reply: is it possible to detect the **specific** IE11 version? For example, the version of my IE is 11.420.10586.0. Is there a way to get all this using Javascript?

I'm currently using Polymer to build a webapp and I found that there is a specific problem that only occurs on IE 11.0.9600.17420 and lower, but newer versions are not affected by this problem and I was trying to show a message to the user saying they need to update the browser.

Comment: Instead of trying to detect the version you should probably write a test for the bug if it's not too complicated.

Comment: You must to try to solve the problem in a global way and not a fixing workaround to specific version of browser. However, the answer to your question is **no**. The user agent string doesn't includes the complete version.

Comment: Ok thanks. 
@Marcos, the problem is a webcomponents issue - they know about it but never fixed it because Microsoft IE11 update from March 2015 solved it - [here](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/issues/235)

So it's not up to me, but some people in my organization still user older versions.

Instead, I'll use the window.onerror to detect the problem and ask the user to update the browser.

Comment: Ok, but I insist that you can't get that browser version, only the major version. Sorry :( . The solution listening errors is fine, I guess.

Comment: Yes, that part I got, thank you!

Comment: Be careful with catching errors - if you are not looking for the specific error in the line of code you expect it in (e.g. in a higher block) you could potentially catch other errors unintentionally and be asking them to upgrade when it may have nothing to do with the browser version.

Comment: I check if the error caught is the specific error I get when I have this problem, otherwise it continues running.